# Help required in making web page work on a web hosting domain

Tags: php, javascript, html, web-hosting

I need help in making my web page work on a public domain. I uploaded all my files & directories to root folder. How can I specify which file to open i.e. my user interface when url is opened.

Comment: are you useing plesk or cpanel or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but the default file name(s) that the web server looks for when you enter a domain name or directory without a file name are usually

```
index.htm
index.html
index.php (if PHP is installed)
```

(As @T.J. points out, differing additional names are used on Microsoft servers)

give a file one of these names and it will appear automatically.

Comment: @Pekka, actually I know this though had not much practice of this.I deleted all my old files & put one php file with phpinfo() but now when I type uel, it starts a search page

Comment: @Xceptable please add some hard data to your question - what URL are you requesting, what files are there etc.

Comment: @Pekka, I had made an application using personal web server.I had made  an account on a free web hosting domain. I had some old version of same application there that opens.Now I delete all old files from web server & put new files but now when I type url that opens my web page on web server do not find anything & opens a search engine there. I even deleted all files & made an index.php file with phpinfo() inside but same result. I put this file in root folder.This whole what I did. So what could be wrong with this.

Comment: That's strange: If all the old files are deleted, this shouldn't happen. No idea what this could be - are you sure you are in the right directory / on the right server?

Comment: Yes, I checked it many times. One more thing is can you tell some good free web hosting domain.

Comment: @XCeptable nope, I don't know any good free ones that support PHP.

Comment: @Pekka, OK, that was a trivial problem. As I wrote that I had little experience of using online web hosting server. It has same folders' structure as a personal web server has. So htdocs is also root there. I just think that may be I uploaded that folder from personal web server & delete that too.& uploaded new files to real root that's why they weren't detected. thanks again 4 your help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Apache: take a look at [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)